# Why am I getting different results depending on whether I use an iPad or and iPhone in the Simulator?

Tags: ios

I am getting different, and somewhat strange, values when I grab data from UserDefaults. The values depend on whether the Simulator is set on an iPhone or an iPad. (The same thing happens when I test on an actual device.)

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    tempUnitsLabel.text = defaults.string(forKey: distanceUnitsKey)
    tempCenterLabel.text = defaults.string(forKey: centerKey)
    tempSizeLabel.text = defaults.string(forKey: sizeKey)
```

The three objects in my Settings Bundle are a multi-value, a toggle switch and a slider (with values in the Settings app of miles, NO and 0.5, respectively). Simulating an iPhone I get miles, 0 and 0.5. Simulating an iPad I get miles, NO and 1. How can this be?

Comment: `UserDefaults` are separate for every device. If you want to store data between devices, consider `Keychain`.

Comment: Yes, they are all stored on their own devices. You should usually stick with `UserDefaults`, unless you need the data to transfer (`Keychain`) or you are marking whether the user has made a purchase (as the `UserDefaults` `plist` can easily be changed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Defaults is like a sewer. What you get out of it depends upon what you put into it. At some previous time, in code you did not show us, different values were put in depending on device type. Now you are just reading them back out.